# Unit test rollback in a multi-tenant setup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

When converting a spring boot application to a schema-based multi-tenancy setup I stumble upon an issue getting original unit tests to work, again.
In my setup there are two custom instances of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` (one of them using a MultiTenantConnectionProvider and `@Primary` annotation) and two instances of custom `JpaTransactionManager` (one with `@Primary` annotation).

The original unit test is equipped with `@SpringBootTest`, `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`, `@Sql` and `@Transactional` annotations on class level.

The problem is that the rollback after each unit test method is not working as expected, anymore. According the log it seems that rollback is initiated, however the sql code executed from the `@SQL` annotation leads to a duplicate key exception - hence indicating that the rollback did not take place.

A workaround for getting the tests working again is using `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`. However, this would only be a workaround causing a huge increase in test execution time if I really can't figure out what is going on.

Does somebody have some input on this? I guess it has something to do with `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` but after hours I still can't find the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I made a further important observation:
The `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` does not have a DataSource set per default (should be resolved according the current tenant). Now, for testing purposes, if I set the `DataSource` in the configuration with `emf.setDataSource(datasource);` the unit tests inlcuding the rollback works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is now:

```
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @BeforeAll
    public void init() {
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
```

Furthermore, I double-checked, that transaction rollback works in production code as expected. I can live with this solution but I'm still curious why this workaround is required. `JpaTransactionManager` uses it's `afterPropertiesSet()` to set the `DataSource` received from the `EntityManager`. In a multi-tenancy setup this `DataSource` is `null` by design (as it should be resolved depending on the requested tenant). It seems that for testing a non-null `DataSource` reference from the transaction manager is required (while it seems not to be required in production code).